# How to find a mathematical method to solve this big value recursion problem?

Tags: python

A python code with a recursion function. To calculate this is to slow by PC. So do there have a easy way to find the answer of this python code?

```py
def rec(n):
    if n<1:
      return 1
    return rec(n//4)+rec(n//2)
print(rec(12345678987654321))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could look into expanding the recurrence relation, or you could simply use [memoization](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php):

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return helper

@memoize
def rec(n):
    if n<1:
      return 1
    return rec(n//4)+rec(n//2)

print(rec(12345678987654321))
```

The above takes ~30ms on my computer, including the time it takes to start the Python interpreter.

The memoization speeds things up by not computing `rec()` for the same value of `n` more than once (the original version repeats the same computations over and over again, wasting a lot of CPU cycles).

Comment: Thank you very much. This idea is so smart.

Comment: the idea is well known not smart @user7128936

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lru_cache` which is in  `functools` module.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html
As the docs state

> Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up to the maxsize most recent calls. It can save time when an expensive or I/O bound function is periodically called with the same arguments

If maxsize is set to `None` the cache grows without bound.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize = None)
def rec(n):
    if n < 1:
        return  1
    return rec(n // 4) + rec(n // 2)
print(rec(12345678987654321))
```

Time metrics:

```
times = timeit.timeit(setup = 'from __main__ import rec',
stmt = 'print(rec(12345678987654321))', number = 1)
```

With `lru_cache`

```
225851433717
0.00023956200311658904
```

Without `lru_cache`

```
More than 2 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns the Xth Fibonacci number where X = log(n)+3.  Since obtaining the Xth Fibonacci number has an O(X) performance and we are supplying it with log(n). This will give *O(log(n))* performance which will be similar to the memoized version but using simpler operations. So the function should run even faster:

```
def fibo(n):
    a,b=1,1
    for _ in range(n-1): a,b = b,a+b
    return a

from math import log
def rec2(n) : 
    return fibo(int(log(n,2)+3))

print(rec2(12345678987654321)) # 225851433717
```

For n = 12345678987654321, this performs roughly 5 times faster than the memoized version of the original rec() function.

You could also get the performance gain by not making two recursive calls at each iteration.  This would require returning two values so that n//4 (the next iteration) can be brought up to the calling function.

```
def rec3(n):
    if n<1 :return 1,1
    a,b = rec3(n//2)
    return a+b,a 

rec3(12345678987654321)[0] # 225851433717
```

This is slower than the Fibonacci approach but still faster than the memoized original.

Test results for 1000 runs (2.9 GHz Intel Core i9 laptop):

```
rec(12345678987654321)     0.027 sec (Memoized on lru_cache, cleared each run)
rec2(12345678987654321)    0.005 sec (Fibonacci)
                           0.002 sec (fastFibo, see EDIT below)
rec3(12345678987654321)[0] 0.013 sec (Single Recursion)
```

**EDIT**
If you want to make the Fibonacci approach even faster (2x), you can use this non-iterative `fastFibo()` function to obtain the Nth Fibonacci number:

```
from math import sqrt

sqrt5 = sqrt(5)
golden_ratio = (1 + sqrt5) / 2

def fastFibo(n):
    approx = (golden_ratio**n - (1 - golden_ratio)**n) / sqrt5
    return int(round(approx))
```

This will allow you to write the function as a purely mathematical formula with no iterations/recursions and a performance of O(1):

```
from math import log,sqrt
sqrt5 = sqrt(5)
golden_ratio = (1 + sqrt5) / 2
def rec4(n):
    n = int(log(n,2)+3)
    result = (golden_ratio**n - (1 - golden_ratio)**n) / sqrt5
    return int(round(result))
```

*note that `fastFibo()` is an approximation (good up to 70) so this `rec4()` solution will only be valid up to n = 2^67  (147573952589676412928)*

Comment: How do you see the original problem is just thf  fibonacci mumbers?

Comment: Printed out the results for the first 100 values of n and saw the pattern. Then tested it on larger values.  The second algorithm (with only one recursive call) also gives it away.

Comment: I also had a hunch because of the f(n-1) + f(n) pattern in the original function.  The iteration control values were powers of 2 but still would produce additive results based on 1,1